# TimescaleDB - get retention policy and chunk_time_interval for a table

Tags: timescaledb

Given a hypertable

```
SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time', chunk_time_interval => INTERVAL '1 day');

SELECT add_retention_policy('conditions', INTERVAL '6 months');
```

in TimescaleDB, how can I retrieve the length of both intervals (`chunk_time_interval` and retention policy interval) using a select statement, providing the table name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information about retention policies through the jobs view:

```sql
SELECT schedule_interval, config FROM timescaledb_information.jobs
WHERE hypertable_name = 'conditions'
AND timescaledb_information.jobs.proc_name = 'policy_retention';
```

The output will be something like this:

```sql
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ schedule_interval │                    config                     │
├───────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 1 day             │ {"drop_after": "6 mons", "hypertable_id": 26} │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To get the hypertable, you can get the info from `dimensions` view:

```sql
 select time_interval from timescaledb_information.dimensions where hypertable_name = 'conditions';
┌───────────────┐
│ time_interval │
├───────────────┤
│ 1 day         │
└───────────────┘
(1 row)
```